# Play RTSP in a 64 bit VLC Wrapper in c#

Tags: wrapper, vlc, rtsp

This is long shot but I am desperate so i will ask the question anyway.

I am currently using the excellent vlc wrapper created by Roman Ginzburg.  This is the link to the article/code:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109639/nVLC

I have an IP camera that returns a RTSP stream to my C# Winform App using his wrapper.  I have download the latest 64 bit version of VLC.  I have made sure I am using the correct DLLs and Plugins directory.

I have changed my target platform to be 'Any CPU'.

I use the exact same arguments (passed to libVLC.dll).

They are:

```
        string[] args2 = new string[] 
         {
             "-vvv",
            "-I", 
            "dummy",                  
            "--vcodec=h264",
            "--ignore-config", 
            "--no-osd",
            "--disable-screensaver",
            "--ffmpeg-hw",
            "--live-caching=100 ",
            "--rtsp-caching=100",
            "--realrtsp-caching=100",
            "--network-caching=0",
            "--skip-frames",
            "--drop-late-frames",
            "--plugin-path=./plugins" 
         };
```

{I have tried commenting out/in all scenarios)

I run the project and I get a stream of black images.  Yet If I open a DOS prompt and type in vlc.exe 'my rtsp url' then vlc starts up and streams my rtsp.

Now I read somewhere that VLC will automatically add the additional command arguments it needs and upon further inspection it is using live555. I have tried adding this as an argument and if i add 'live555', I get no error but no image. If I add '--live555' I get an error telling me the argument is no good.

So..

Either I have missed something and have not copied all the required files - which i doubt.
Or, it is down to the arguments I need to pass.  If I knew how to pass 'live555' as an argument then i can rule that in or out.

Any advice/opinions would be merciful.

Thanks

Comment: Just check if the IP Camera supports 64bit. I was facing with a similar problem. Recently, a new 64bit firmware was updated to the Ipcamera.